# Why does puppeteer page.goto() throw a timeout error?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, serverless

The following code throws an error, why?

> Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 60000ms exceeded

I'm using puppeteer version 1.19.0

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setCacheEnabled(false);

  try {
    const response = await page.goto("https://www.gatsbyjs.com", {
      waitUntil: "networkidle0",
      timeout: 60000
    });

    console.log("Status code:", response.status());
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Some other URLs work fine, so I wonder if there is anything special with this particular URL?

Answer (score 4):

If you change the waitUntil : "networkidle2" . There is no time out.

> networkidle2 - consider navigation to be finished when there are no
>   more than 2 network connections for at least 500 ms.

As pointed out in Erez's answer . 'serviceworker' may be holding the connection.You can check it by going to chrome://serviceworker-internals/ . Or Devtools -> Application Tab - Service Wokers

```
Serive Worker: chrome://serviceworker-internals/

Scope: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/
Registration ID: 295
Navigation preload enabled: false
Navigation preload header length: 4
Active worker:
Installation Status: ACTIVATED
Running Status: RUNNING
Fetch handler existence: EXISTS
Script: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/sw.js
Version ID: 10330
Renderer process ID: 11892
Renderer thread ID: 18124
DevTools agent route ID: 8

From Network : installingWorker ServiceWorker {scriptURL: "https://www.gatsbyjs.com/sw.js", state: "installing", onerror: null, onstatechange: null}
```

**References :**

[`Navigation Timeout Exceeded` when using `networkidle0` and no insight into what timed out](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1908#issuecomment-434875763)

[Support ServiceWorkers #2634](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2634)

Answer (score 3):

Removing `waitUntil: "networkidle0"` works so I'm assuming the site is still holding a connection to the server.

I couldn't figure out which connection it is (maybe the service worker?) using the developers tools (accessible in non headless mode by running `await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })`)